# Reading from one file to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, formatting, html-parsing

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm overlooking. I've done this kind of operation before. I'm reading from htmlfile, which is my template file, and writing to htmlfile2 which is my actual report. Before anyone freaks out, the HTML isn't being used on a website or anything, it's just being used as a convenient means to display report data. I found rgraph, a tool for creating HTML5 graphs, and thought, "Wow, this is perfect! I don't even have to code a GUI now and I can easily save my report results!"

My htmlfile has several lines with comments that contain text that tells my program that said line needs replaced in htmlfile2. If I use print statements to check which loops are executing, the proper loops execute every time. For some reason the text just never changes. It's as if the write function takes place, but doesn't work, it fails silently. The value that is in the template is NOT in the python code anywhere, so the write is simply not doing it's job, even though the loop has been entered. I've tried a few different if conditions, just to see if there would be any change, hence the startswith vs the ==, etc. Help???

```
def editHTML(self, searchT, replaceT):
    if os.path.isfile('C:/MetReports/report.html'):
        with open('C:/MetReports/report.html') as htmlfile:
            with open('C:/MetReports/report2.html', 'w') as htmlfile2:
                for line in htmlfile:
                    if searchT in line:
                        if searchT.startswith('REP1'):
                            tester = "\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs', 0,100, " + str(replaceT) + ") //REP1\n"
                            htmlfile2.write(tester)
                        elif searchT == 'REP2':
                            tester2 = "\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs2', 0,100, " + str(replaceT) + ") //REP2\n"
                            htmlfile2.write(tester2)
                        elif searchT == 'REP3':
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs3', 0,1000, " + str(replaceT) + ") //REP3\n")
                        elif searchT == 'REP4':
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs4', 0,30, " + str(replaceT) + ") //REP4\n")
                        elif searchT == 'REP5':
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs5', 0,30, " + str(replaceT) + ") //REP5\n")
                    elif searchT not in line:
                        htmlfile2.write(line)
```

Edit for clarification:

Example lines from htmlfile:

```
<canvas id="cvs" width="400" height="250" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 15px">[No canvas support]</canvas>
        <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs', 0,100, 25) //REP1
            .set('angles.start', RGraph.PI - 0.5)
            .set('angles.end', RGraph.TWOPI + 0.5)
```

The 25 is the number that should change when the loop is entered and the searchT variable is subbed in. So an example run would look like:

```
editHTML('REP1', 30)
```

which should change only one line above, replacing the 25 with the 30.

EDIT 2:

It is as I thought, the text is being overwritten by the other if statement running when it shouldn't be. I placed "exit(0) after one of the writes and checked my file and the information in it was correct for that value alone..

EDIT 3:

Solution in comments. For anyone who ever has a similar issue in the future, always remember, debug, debug, debug! Step into your processes one by one and you'll find your issue. In my case, I called a function without realizing that it would overwrite my output file with the contents of the input file.

Comment: None of the writes do anything?  Or just some of them?

Comment: It seems like all but the last write refuse to work. It's almost as if the htmlfile2.write(line) is overwriting the changed lines, even though the "if searchT not in line" should stop it from doing that.

Comment: You should provide a minimal complete example, including the contents of the files (one or two lines should be sufficient) and the call parameters.

Comment: try using find(...) > -1 instead of contains. Perhaps there are whitespaces you missed

Comment: I switched from "if searchT in line" to "if line.find(searchT) > -1" without any luck.

Comment: Your code works for me, as it is.  I just removed `self`, it's unused.

Comment: In my case it's used, because editHTML is part of a class, and in order to call the function from outside of the class and send parameters, self needs to be included in the definition.

The fact that this works for you, is weird because I can't for the life of me find anything wrong with my loop structure. I've changed it like 10 times since posting this and I've got nothing. For some reason, the code is always overwritten by the default.

Even if the loops were to rerun, the lines that need text replaced should always include the indicator text regardless of run.

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS I'M AN IDIOT. I figured it out....

The code works, it's overwriting itself because when I call editHTML a second time, I'm searching for a different indicator, so the last indicator doesn't match and gets overwritten by the template file!!!

GAH!

Temporary Solution: Update the template file after every run. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @TheFunk If you have found a solution then please take some time to post is as a proper answer and accept it. This lets other users know that this question is solved and the answer can be used as a reference in the future too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my issue I had to look at two things: loop structure, and process. My main function creates an object which has the function editHTML, in my case when I called editHTML multiple times, since I was reading from a static file (a template if you will) and searching for too specific criteria, I ended up overwriting lines. I have since changed the entire structure to make it simpler. Now, editHTML is only called a single time and instead of having to focus on how many times I needed this function to be called, and what that would do to my text, the function is called once, does all the work I need it to do in that single run, and resets itself should the user choose to run it again.

Now it just needs optimized. Here is the new editHTML code, it is now passed a list (as opposed to two strings) as it's sole argument.

```
   def editHTML(self, replaceT):
    if os.path.isfile('C:/MetReports/report.html'):
        with open('C:/MetReports/report.html') as htmlfile:
            with open('C:/MetReports/report2.html', 'w') as htmlfile2:
                fixer = '//REP'
                count = 0
                for line in htmlfile:
                    if line.find(fixer) == -1:
                        htmlfile2.write(line)
                    else:
                        if count == 0:
                            print("running 1")
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs', 0,100, " + str(replaceT[0]) + ") //REP1\n")
                        elif count == 1:
                            print("running 2")
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs2', 0,100, " + str(replaceT[1]) + ") //REP2\n")
                        elif count == 2:
                            print("running 3")
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs3', 0,1000, " + str(replaceT[2]) + ") //REP3\n")
                        elif count == 3:
                            print("running 4")
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs4', 0,30, " + str(replaceT[3]) + ") //REP4\n")
                        elif count == 4:
                            print("running 5")
                            htmlfile2.write("\t\t\tvar meter = new RGraph.Meter('cvs5', 0,30, " + str(replaceT[4]) + ") //REP5\n")
                        count += 1
```